# UDF for different if calculations for each row in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a user defined function in Excel VBA to check each cell in a row and output an answer. This is an Example:

```
A       B       C       D
Name    Age Income  Gender
Adam    28  50-60K  M
John    32  40-50K  M
Maria   65  20-30K  F
Ben     22  50-60K  M
Jen     45  60-70K  F
```

In the above array, I want to be able to pass each row to the function. The function should Output a Group name for each of these people based on some "if" conditions. How can I do this?

Also, Coln. C and Coln. D are TEXT fields while Coln B isnt. Grouping condition examples are:

"If age<30 and income="50-60K"or"40-50K" then the function should output to column E saying "GroupA"

ElseIf age>30 and gender="F" then function should output it as "group B"
Elseif

I know this can be done with standard Excel Nested Ifs but I have too many conditions and Excel says that there are too many conditions when I write them in the formula bar.

I have my code below but Im not sure what Im doing wrong.

```
Function Trial(Range)

Dim r As Long

r = ActiveCell.Row

For Each Cell In Range

If Cells(r, 2).Value < 30 And Cells(r, 3).Value = "50-60k" Or Cells(r, 3).Value = "40-50k" Then
Trial= "Group A"
ElseIf Cells(r, 2).Value > 30 And Cells(r, 4).Value ="F" Then
Trial= "Group B"
End If

Next Cell

End Function
```

Comment: Excel 2003 can have 7 nested if's, what version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you REALLY need a UDF, then in E2, enter:

**=Trial(A2:D2)**

and the UDF syntax like:

```
Public Function Trial(r As Range) As String
    Trial = ""
    If r(2) < 30 And (r(3) = "50-60k" Or r(3) = "40-50k") Then
        Trial = "GroupA"
    End If
End Function
```

Continue adding as many **If** s as you require

Answer (score 1):

> "If age<30 and income="50-60K"or"40-50K" then the function should output to column E saying "GroupA"
>
> ElseIf age>30 and gender="F" then function should output it as "group B" Elseif

Too many `Ifs`? How?

Try this

`=IF(B2<30,IF(OR(C2="50-60K",C2="40-50K"),"GroupA",""),IF(AND(B2>30,D2="F"),"GroupB",""))`

[image]

Comment: Thanks Siddharth.. The above use case was just an example. For my actual scenario, I have many groups and many many more conditions. Hence I thought VBA could help automate this process.

I get excel error "You've entered too many arguments for this function"

Comment: Then Why waste our time by giving scenarios which don't exist :) You could have mentioned that in the question that the above was just an example...

Comment: Sorry about that.I am new to this. Was learning how to do it in VBA and thought I can explain what i wanted easily thru this example. Your answer was very helpful though.